# how to apply Music Radio loading in UIAlertController?

Tags: swift, loading, uialertcontroller

I want to create this loading style in my project,i really dont know how.I am really a beginner to swift ui components.I want to add this loading style in my alert view and after getting the results i want to dismiss.So,i want to know about how to make it and add to the alert view to make present and dismiss,Any help please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can not do it into default alert view but you can create a custom view and achieve this.

For that you need one circle image and you can add that into Image view and add one label which has text Loading.. add both into View like shown into below image:

[image]

After that connect outlet for all of this. and you can show that view as per your need and when you show this view you can rotate image with this code:

```
func rotateViewLayer() {
    let rotateView = CABasicAnimation()

    rotateView.fromValue = 0.degreesToRadian
    rotateView.toValue = 360.degreesToRadian
    rotateView.duration = 1
    rotateView.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    rotateView.removedOnCompletion = false
    rotateView.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    rotateView.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    imageView.layer.addAnimation(rotateView, forKey: "transform.rotation.z")
}
```

And you will need this extension:

```
extension Int {
var degreesToRadian : CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(self) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }
}
```

and when you hide this view you can remove animation from imageview with this:

```
imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

And you can check result [HERE](http://gyazo.com/58ed074db62f3ea173267b749dbabdd2).

You can use [THIS](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) Amazing library too.

And [HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Loading-View) is complete working project.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I got it sir.But there is a little glitch when it finish everytime it rotate,can you fix that too?Thank you sir.This really help me a lot to learn.If you don't mind or busy,can you do that like itunes red style,Thanks

Comment: I can not found that kind of image you have to create one..and you can use this image: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=red+circle+png+Image&espv=2&biw=1633&bih=932&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ7AlqFQoTCJ60jse_icYCFcJ6vAodY-kANw#imgrc=v2VxJxj2BszReM%253A%3BTo8j83hHvNeo7M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mahati.net%252Fbg%252FredCircle.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mahati.net%252F%3B1000%3B1000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80355/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-62shark).

Comment: Umm Sir glitch still happening when i use homeTargetAcq_circle.png.:( .I am sorry.But your answer really helpful.

Comment: I solved it by changing this code "rotateView.repeatCount = Float(1200000)".I dont know it might lose some performance or not.But it work.

Comment: Glad that you found it by your self..:)